# PHP Curl http requests with proxy fails 95% of times, why?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, curl, proxy

Using curl command on php, i want to request a simple get to "https://www.instagram.com".

```
$curl->get("https://www.instagram.com");
```

When I don't use Proxy for my curl it usually completes (sometimes curl fails for the first time and then retries and it goes through the second time).

```
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 11:35:56 GMT
< Location: https://instagram.com/
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Content-Length: 178
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #1 to host www.instagram.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://instagram.com/'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.88.218.232...
* Connected to instagram.com (54.88.218.232) port 443 (#2)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*        server certificate verification SKIPPED
*        common name: *.instagram.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=US,ST=CA,L=Menlo Park,O=Instagram LLC,CN=*.instagram.com
*        start date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 00:00:00 GMT

*        expire date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 12:00:00 GMT

*        issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
*        compression: NULL
*        cipher: AES-128-CBC
*        MAC: SHA1
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: instagram.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 11:35:59 GMT
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
* Added cookie csrftoken="c44fef8af558485be2ff78da940bdfd6" for domain instagram.com, path /, expire 1465558381
< Set-Cookie: csrftoken=c44fef8af558485be2ff78da940bdfd6; expires=Fri, 10-Jun-2016 11:35:59 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
* Added cookie mid="VXrEHwAEAAE0R2ZgV8aoF27i7VD7" for domain instagram.com, path /, expire 2064828781
< Set-Cookie: mid=VXrEHwAEAAE0R2ZgV8aoF27i7VD7; expires=Thu, 07-Jun-2035 11:35:59 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/
< Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 3049
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #2 to host instagram.com left intact
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 not-logged-in "> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in "> <!--<![endif]-->
```

The problem is when I use proxy on my curl, on 95% of times it hangs on "found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" and then it gets timeout.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.instagram.com/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 104.144.1.1...
* Connected to 104.144.1.1 (104.144.1.1) port 21269 (#1)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.instagram.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'proxyusername'
> CONNECT www.instagram.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.instagram.com:443
Proxy-Authorization: Basic bW9oYW1tYWdoYToyazMzODczMw==
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0

< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 1
```

Why using proxy will make curl act this way on ubuntu? on Windows OS the same exact code executes and runs very fast, and fetches the instagram.com page, but on Ubuntu it failes 95% of the time.

Here is the options of curl:

```
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_POST, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_ENCODING, $this->compression );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file );
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );

// Proxy settings
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $url);
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
curl_setopt ( $this->process, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $userpass);
```

Here is the result of phpinfo() on curl:

```
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.35.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => Yes
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => GnuTLS/2.12.23
ZLib Version => 1.2.8
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have some sort of trouble with your certs... give the following a try, it's worked for me in the past with similar (but different) issues.

```
update-ca-certificates -f
apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

For your reference, here's the man for update-ca-certificates

> update-ca-certificates   is   a  program  that  updates  the 
>   directory    /etc/ssl/certs to hold SSL certificates and generates
>   certificates.crt,    a concatenated single-file list of certificates.
>
> It reads the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf. Each line gives a
>   pathname    of a CA certificate under  /usr/share/ca-certificates 
>   that  should  be    trusted.  Lines that begin with "#" are comment
>   lines and thus ignored.    Lines that begin with "!" are deselected,
>   causing the  deactivation  of    the CA certificate in question.
>   Certificates must have a .crt extension    in order to be included by
>   update-ca-certificates.
>
> Furthermore  all  certificates  with  a  .crt  extension  found
>   below    /usr/local/share/ca-certificates   are   also  included  as 
>   implicitly    trusted.